# Grouping the message based on one field in mule data weaver

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a requirement where I want to filter the incoming message based on the category='E'. So if the category = 'I', it should be trimmed off the message.

### Sample Input

```
<DataSet>
    <SubDataSet>
        <DataNum>TEXU9022186</DataNum>
        <Category>E</Category>                             
    </SubDataSet>
    <SubDataSet>
        <DataNum>TEXU9022186T</DataNum>
        <Category>I</Category>                                  
    </SubDataSet>
    <SubDataSet>
        <DataNum>TEXU9022186T</DataNum>
        <Category>E</Category>
    </SubDataSet>
</DataSet>
```

### Sample Output

```
<DataSet>
    <SubDataSet>
        <DataNum>TEXU9022186</DataNum>
        <Category>E</Category>                             
    </SubDataSet>
    <SubDataSet>
        <DataNum>TEXU9022186T</DataNum>
        <Category>E</Category>                                  
    </SubDataSet>
</DataSet>
```

Could you please how to achieve this by mule dataweaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter in dataweave script as

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{DataSet : payload.DataSet.*SubDataSet filter ($.Category == "E")}
```

Hope this helps..